# Is it a bad practice to use an input stream to construct an object?

Tags: java

Would it be considered bad practice to pass a stream/reader to a container class when reading data from a file, as opposed to reading the data within the calling method, then passing the values as parameters?

**For example**

```
public DummyClass(DataInputStream input) throws IOException {
    this.valueA = input.readInt();
    this.valueB = input.readInt();
}
```

**Opposed to**

```
public DummyClass(int a, int b) {
    this.valueA = a;
    this.valueB = b;
}
```

Comment: The second method shouldn't throw an `IOException`, should it?

Comment: One argument against this: You just tied one particular serialization to the data object, violating S (and possibly O and I) of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Comment: @Gendarme Oops, I must have forgotten to omit it when I copy/pasted the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends from the kind of code.

If your code is related to a stream is correct to build the object directly from the stream.

If you build objects that are not related to a stream is a bad practice to pass as a parameter a stream because you can couple objects that are not each other related.

Here some example:

With stream parameter

- A class that convert a stream in another stream
- A class that convert a stream to an Iterator
- A class that builds an object from a stream, like a stream of json.

Without a stream

- A class that create a Point from a Stream. Because a Point is not related to a stream

Comment: The primary purpose of the object is to read in a tree of data and store it, which wouldn't really be stream related. As the structure of the tree depends on what type of tree it is, I was planning to have a child class for each different type of tree. This really did feel like bad practice, though. Thank you for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the purpose of the object.

If this is a domain object, it's good to *not* couple it to any storage/transfer representation.

If however, this is an object intended to implement an encoding/decoding scheme, then it's a reasonable constructor to use.

Answer (score 1):

As per my opinion, You should not pass the Stream object in your class. Because now

1. we are giving one more responsibility to the class(DummyClass) to read data, which is not its job.
2. The DummyClass will be more coupled.
3. We don't have flexibility to pass the data from some other resources, If needed.